# ToolStripControlHost's AutoSize does not function correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the code below, I tried to display a popup above the button when the button is pressed, but the AutoSize of ToolStripControlHost does not work properly and the entire contents are not displayed.
In addition to that, the popup is displayed slightly above the button, even though the button location is specified.
How can I solve this problem?
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var panel1 = new Panel();

            var label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = "12345\nabsde\nlllllllllllllllllA\nVWXYZ\nZZZZZZZZZZZZZZA";
            label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            label1.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            label1.AutoSize = true;
            label1.Size = Size.Empty;
            label1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            panel1.Controls.Add(label1);

            var toolStripControlHost = new ToolStripControlHost(panel1);
            toolStripControlHost.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            toolStripControlHost.Padding = Padding.Empty;
            toolStripControlHost.BackColor = SystemColors.Info;
            toolStripControlHost.AutoSize = true;
            toolStripControlHost.Size = Size.Empty;

            var toolStripDropDown = new ToolStripDropDown();
            toolStripDropDown.Margin = Padding.Empty;
            toolStripDropDown.Padding = Padding.Empty;
            toolStripDropDown.DropShadowEnabled = false;
            toolStripDropDown.AutoSize = true;
            toolStripDropDown.Size = Size.Empty;
            toolStripDropDown.Items.Add(toolStripControlHost);
            toolStripDropDown.Show(this, button1.Location, ToolStripDropDownDirection.AboveRight);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the font changes when a control is inserted into toolStripControlHost, so I inserted the following code to try it out and make the font explicit, and it works fine now.

```
toolStripControlHost.Font = DefaultFont;
```